# Why Linux process is defunct but its parent process is still alive?

Tags: linux

In man page of ps it describes defunct as "Defunct ("zombie") process, terminated but not reaped by its parent".
The process use pipes to communicate with its parent. In the logs I verified it has closed pipes and exited normally.

Why it becomes defunct instead of properly destroyed?

Is there something the parent process can do to avoid such situations?

In top this process has no allocated memory, which confirms it has exited normally.

> osysops  42884 42820  0 06:55 ?        00:00:03 [lecw]

Comment: "terminated but not reaped by its parent". It tells you right there what the parent needs to do. It needs to reap the child. In C parlance that means calling one of the [wait](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/wait.2.html) functions.

Comment: is it necessary to wait for a child process even if parent process has no use of the child's return code? moreover, wait() will block the process, that is an undesirable behavior.